# What are bloating controls

Tags: c#

What are bloating controls?
Can anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a term which can be used to describe a variety of things, e.g. it is commonly used by critics of ASP.NET WebForms where, if you are making heavy use of pre-built WebControls you have little control of the generated HTML, which in many cases appears 'bloated' (large) and 'unclean', 'messy', etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure 'bloating' is exactly what you mean.  Some controls could be called 'bloated'.

In that case it means that some controls offer a great deal of functionality which in most cases is not required.  Grid controls tend to be fairly bloated because they expose functionality for sorting, filtering, binding, templating etc.. but it's unlikely that you'll use all of this in a single implementation of the grid so you're taking up much more memory than you actually need which could potentially cause performance issues.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess people are referring to the fact that some GUI controls are very big and thus a bit hard to understand / use.